# Combine two collections with predicate using Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have two collections of type `Entity`.

```
class Entity {
    long id;
    // other fields
}

Collection<Entity> first = ...
Collection<Entity> second = ...
```

I need to combine them in a such way that all elements in `first` should be replaced by elements from `second` if their ids are equal.

So, e.g if `first` contains `[{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 3}]` and `second` contains `[{"id": 3}, {"id": 4}, {"id": 5}]`

the result should be like this: `[{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 3}, {"id": 4}, {"id": 5}]` where `{"id": 3}` from `second` replaced `{"id": 3}` from first.

Is there a way how to implement it in a Java 8 way, using Stream API.

Comment: You mean the stream form of `first.removeAll(second).addAll(second)`?

Answer (score 2):

While it is possible to do the entire operation with one stream operation, the result would not be very efficient due to the repeated iteration over the collections. It’s strongly recommended to use two operations here

```
Map<Long,Entity> secondById = second.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entity::getId, Function.identity()));

Collection<Entity> result = first.stream()
    .map(e -> secondById.getOrDefault(e.getId(), e))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that I took your task description “elements in `first` should be replaced by elements from `second` if their ids are equal” literally, e.g. it will not insert elements from the second not having a matching element in first. If `first` has a defined encounter order, it will be retained.

Note that if `first` is a mutable list, you could replace the elements in-place:

```
List<Entity> first = ...
Collection<Entity> second = ...

Map<Long,Entity> secondById = second.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entity::getId, Function.identity()));

first.replaceAll(e -> secondById.getOrDefault(e.getId(), e));
```

Changing it to not just replace elements of `first`, but add all elements of `second` is not so hard:

```
Map<Long,Entity> secondById = second.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entity::getId, Function.identity()));

Collection<Entity> result = Stream.concat(
    first.stream().filter(e -> !secondById.containsKey(e.getId())),
    second.stream()
  ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some old-fashioned, simple `Collection` methods can help you :

```
first.removeAll(second);
first.addAll(second);
```

Note you have to implement both `hashCode` and `equals` to use `id` as a parameter in your Entity class.

#### Ideone demo

---

**Edit**

As you cannot change `equals`, you can use [`Collection.removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) to replicate the effect of `removeAll`:

```
second.forEach(entity2 -> first.removeIf(entity1 -> entity1.getId() == entity2.getId()));
first.addAll(second);
```

#### Ideone demo 2

Comment: thank you, but it won't work since I mentioned that I want to compare two Entity by only one field which is id. Besides that I have equals/hashcode implemented and it uses all fields, not only id, co contains() method won't work here. "if their ids are equal"

Comment: check my edit @user3127896 you can use removeIf in this case

Comment: I would prefer this as long as the sets are not too large. Probably not the most efficient solution due to the repeated iteration, but certainly very readable.

Comment: Thank you @MalteHartwig i appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

The stream form of `first.removeAll(second).addAll(second)` so to say:

```
Stream<Entity> result = Stream.concat(
    first.stream().filter(entity -> !second.contains(entity)),
    second.stream());
```

This assumes that the equal entities in `second` differ from `first` by a non-id field value, not relevant for equality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Map.merge(..) to chose the newer record. In the example bellow it is functionally equivalent to Map.put(..), but allows you to compare other Entity attributes, such as a creation timestamp or other.

```
// Extract Entity::getId as a Map key, and keep the Entity object as value
Map<Long, Entity> result = first.stream()
               .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entity::getId, Function.identity()));

// Merge second collection into the result map, overwriting existing records  
second.forEach(entity -> result.merge(entity.getId(), entity, (oldVal, newVal) -> newVal));

// Print result
result.values().forEach(System.out::println);
```

If you want to use Stream API only, then you can concat the two Collections into a single Stream using Stream.concat(...) and then write a custom Collector

```
Map<Long, Entity> result2 = Stream.concat(first.stream(), second.stream())
        .collect(LinkedHashMap::new, // the placeholder type
                (map, entity) -> map.merge(entity.getId(), entity, (oldVal, newVal) -> newVal),
                (map1, map2) -> {}); // parallel processing will reorder the concat stream so ignore
```